# Verificar se a fonte de instalação é da play store

Tags: java, android, google-play

Olá, estava pensando em fazer uma versão **PRO**(sem anúncio) do meu App Android, só que eu gostaria de saber como funciona a verificação da fonte, se foi instalado pela a play store ou o usuário baixo o apk e instalou, ai no caso aparecia uma mensagem: *Você não comprou o App*.

Alguém pode me explicar como funciona esse processo?

Comment: Voce pode usar o método [getInstallerPackageName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29) da classe `PackageManager` para saber se veio da play store, tem que verificar o pacote para isto.

Comment: Valeu, isso que eu queria saber e vou estudar sobre.

Comment: @gato Agora sou eu quem pergunta: por que não coloca uma resposta?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método `String getInstallerPackageName(String packageName)` da classe `PackageManager` ele vai retornar o nome do pacote correspondente ao pacote de instalação da play store, você só precisa passar o pacote atual da sua aplicação para ele e fazer a verificação.

Veja um pequeno exemplo de como implementar e usar o método `getInstallerPackageName` abaixo:

```
public boolean isInstalledFromMarket(String pkgName)
        throws NameNotFoundException { 
    String installerPkg = pkgMngr.getInstallerPackageName(pkgName);
    boolean installedFromMarket = "com.google.android.feedback".equals(installerPkg);
    return installedFromMarket;
}
```

A variável `pkgMngr` é uma instancia da classe `PackageManager`, como foi dito acima, e ela é necessária.

Fontes:
[Documentação do método getInstallerPackageName](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29)
[Exemplo da implementação do método getInstallerPackageName.](https://github.com/droidparts/droidparts/blob/8de90ee86cafa284fea5b02ab8f566ad70602406/droidparts/src/org/droidparts/util/AppUtils2.java)

Comment: Obrigado pelo o exemplo!

Answer (score 0):

Se for da Google Play o metodo PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName() deveria retornar "com.android.vending". Da uma olhada nesse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809438/how-to-know-an-application-is-installed-from-google-play-or-side-load/16862957#16862957)

Mas acho que você terá que ver também se o app foi comprado. [How to secure my app against piracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9865162/how-to-secure-my-app-against-piracy)

Comment: Grato pela a resposta!